# I am having issues updating Gitlab-ce to the latest version (gitlab-ce-16.8.1-ce.0.el7.x86_64.rpm)

Tags: repository, yum, gitlab-ce

I am having issues updating Gitlab-ce to the latest version (gitlab-ce-16.8.1-ce.0.el7.x86_64.rpm) when I perform the update via 'yum update' on the CentOS 7 server. I encounter the following problem ( gitlab-ce-16.8.1-ce.0.el7.x86_ FAILED                                                                12% [===========-                                                                               ] 3.5 kB/s | 134 MB  73:59:33 ETA
https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/el/7/x86_64/gitlab-ce-16.8.1-ce.0.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds')
). Other packages on the operating system update normally, except for the Git package. Can you help?

I performed the cleaning and updating of the repositories' cache, but without success.